# How to calculate Markov Chain parameters knowing AR(1) coefficient $\rho$?

Tags: autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Given that a discrete-time two-states (low and high) Markov chain $X_t$ can take two values:
\begin{pmatrix}
X_l\\
X_h
\end{pmatrix}
with its transition probability matrix $P^{T}$:
\begin{pmatrix}
p_1 & 1-p_1 \\
1-p_2 & p_2
\end{pmatrix}

If the mean, standard deviation, and first-order autocorrelation of $X_t$ are $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\rho$ respectively. How can I calculate the values of $X_l$, $X_h$, $p_1$, and $p_2$. Are three moments insufficient for four unknowns?

Following up:
If I introduce the long-term (or called 'initial') state probabilities: $\pi = ({\pi}_1,{\pi}_2)^T$, then I will meet a similar situation to solve 6 unknowns with 5 equations:
\begin{equation}
    \pi_1X_l + \pi_2X_h = \mu
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \pi_1(X_l-\mu)^2 + \pi_2(X_h-\mu)^2 = \sigma^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \pi_1p_1X_l^2+\pi_1(1-p_1)X_lX_h + \pi_2p_2X_h^2 + \pi_2(1-p_2)X_hX_l  = E[X_tX_{t-1}]=\rho E[X_{t-1}^2] = \rho(\mu^2+\sigma^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \pi_1 + \pi_2 = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
         P\pi = \pi
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, in general, having 4 unknowns and 3 parameters is an undercomplete problem. Perhaps in this case it is possible to solve for $X_l$, $X_r$ and $\eta=p_1 / p_2$. Try to calculate the moments and check of all of them can be expressed in terms of these 3 variables. Good luck :)

Comment: On second thought, I am fairly convinced it is impossible. If my original assumption was true, then all 3 moments would only depend on $\eta$ and not on each value of the probability. However, if we double both $p_1$ and $p_2$, while keeping $\eta$ fixed, we increase autocorrelation, as the markov chain starts to wiggle more.

Comment: Yes, this does not solve the problem. The problem is still fully coupled. If you solve the above 5 equations to eliminate $\pi$, you will end up with a fully coupled 3 equation system and 4 unknowns just as before.